# How do I write the data to Real-time Database firebase flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to write data to the realtime database by first logging in users always using firebase (google_auth).
But there is something wrong with my rules ... if I set write and read "true" they obviously go, the same if I just use "auth! = Null" but when I use these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth! = null && auth.uid == $ uid",
        ".write": "auth! = null && auth.uid == $ uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No longer goes. So I assume the problem is that auth.uid is not the same as uid. I am attaching the code used for authentication and data submission.

Login / registration:

```
Future <UserCredential> signInWithGoogle () async {

  final GoogleSignInAccount? userGoogle = await GoogleSignIn (). signIn ();


  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? Google user data =
      await userGoogle? .authentication;


  final credentialsGoogle = GoogleAuthProvider.credential (
    accessToken: Google User data? .accessToken,
    idToken: Google User data? .idToken,
  );

  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential (Google credentials);
}
```

Data sending:

```
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref ();

    await ref.set ({
      "users": {
        "$uid": {
          "name": "John",
        }
      }
    });
```

uid is fetched like this:

```
checkLogin () {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges (). Listen ((User? User) {
    if (user! = null) {
      username = user.displayName;
      uid = user.uid;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it's because of wrong spacing.. edited the rules. Try this please

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it always gives me "FirebaseException ([firebase_database / permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data."

Comment: Have you also logged in before accessing it?

Comment: yes, I also do a print of uid to make sure it's not a null value